# Sum of Column in HTML and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am needing to get the total of a row from a MySQL data base that is listed in an HTML table.

I have tried using separate sql select statements with the as statement for the new row (i.e. `SELECT SUM(product_price) AS order_total FROM orderplace WHERE orderplace_number = '$item'`) as well as using it in the original select statement.

Here is my original code without the total added up. I would like the total in a different row spanning across all columns. Thanks in advance!

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
    <th>Product ID</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
     </tr>
    <?php
$cart = $_COOKIE['crochetdamour'];
if ($cart) {
    $i = 1;
    include('includes/dbc.php');
    $items = explode(',', $cart);
    foreach ($items AS $item) {
        $sql    = "SELECT * FROM orderplace WHERE orderplace_number = '$item'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if ($result == false) {
            $mysql_error = mysqli_error($con);
            echo "There was a query error: $mysql_error";
        } else {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo '<tr><td align="left" id="prodid" name="prodid">' . $row['product_id'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td align="left" id="prodname" name="prodname">' . $row['product_name'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td align="left" class="desctd" id="proddesc" name="proddesc">' . $row['product_size'] . ', ' . $row['product_gender'] . ', ' . $row['product_theme'] . ', ' . $row['product_specs'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td align="left" id="prodprice" name="prodprice">' . $row['product_price'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td align="left"><a href="mycart.php?remove_id=' . $i . '">Remove From Cart</a></td></tr>';
            } //end while
            $i++;
        } //end else
    } //end foreach
} //end if
?>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to this:

```
    foreach ($items AS $item) {
            $sum = 0; //<-------------
            $sql    = "SELECT * FROM orderplace WHERE orderplace_number = '$item'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            if ($result == false) {
                $mysql_error = mysqli_error($con);
                echo "There was a query error: $mysql_error";
            } else {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo '<tr><td align="left" id="prodid" name="prodid">' . $row['product_id'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td align="left" id="prodname" name="prodname">' . $row['product_name'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td align="left" class="desctd" id="proddesc" name="proddesc">' . $row['product_size'] . ', ' . $row['product_gender'] . ', ' . $row['product_theme'] . ', ' . $row['product_specs'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td align="left" id="prodprice" name="prodprice">' . $row['product_price'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td align="left"><a href="mycart.php?remove_id=' . $i . '">Remove From Cart</a></td></tr>';
                    $sum += $row['product_price']; //<--------------
                } //end while
                $i++;
            } //end else
            echo $sum; //<----------------
        } //end foreach
```

Hope it will helps